# Paging in survey in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to create a survey in an ASP.Net project.
My survey is based in a JSON model. Here are my models:

```
        public class Test
        {
            public string testName { get; set; }
            public List<ScoreSubject> scoreSubjects { get; set; }
            public List<Block> blocks { get; set; }
        }

        public class Block
        {
            public string blockName { get; set; }
            public string bodyTitle { get; set; }
            public string bodyText { get; set; }
            public string concludingText { get; set; }
            public List<Question> questions { get; set; }
        }

        public class Question
        {
            public int questionId { get; set; }
            public bool required { get; set; }
            public string questionTextAboveAnswers { get; set; }
            public string questionTextBelowAnswers { get; set; }
            public string warningText { get; set; }
            public string scoreSubject { get; set; }
            public List<Answer> answers { get; set; }
        }


        public class Answer
        {
            public int answerId { get; set; }
            public string answerText { get; set; }
            public int score { get; set; }
            public string warningText { get; set; }
            public int skipQuestions { get; set; }
        }
```

I have 3 blocks, with each some questions. What I tried to do is show an answer in a Panel. On button click: render the next question.

This is a part of my usercontrol:

```
public List<RootNode> rootNode;

        int _CounterBlock;
        int _CounterQuestions;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(!Page.IsPostBack)
            { 
                _CounterBlock = 0;
                _CounterQuestions = 0;
            }


            LoadJson(); //Convert JSON data to models
            SetControls();
            populateDataByIndex();

        }

        private void SetControls()
        {
            testPanel.Visible = true;
            ProceedLanguageButton.Visible = true;
            QuestionsLanguageRadioButtonList.Visible = false;

        }

        public void populateDataByIndex()
        {

            Rootnode list = rootNode.First(); //Always 1st item in array

            //Get block by index
            Block block = list.test.blocks[_CounterBlock];

            //Load next block when there are no answers, or last answer is filled
            if((_CounterQuestions >= block.questions.Count) || block.questions.Count < 0)
            {
                _CounterBlock++;
                _CounterQuestions = 0;
            }


            bodyTitle.Text = block.bodyTitle;
            bodyText.Text = block.bodyText;

            if(block.questions.Count > 0)
            {
                //Show list when questions is not null
                QuestionsLanguageRadioButtonList.Visible = true;

                //Remove existing items from list
                QuestionsLanguageRadioButtonList.Items.Clear();

                //Show label and question
                Question question = block.questions[_CounterQuestions];
                questionLabel.Text = question.questionTextAboveAnswers;

                foreach(var answer in question.answers)
                {
                    QuestionsLanguageRadioButtonList.Items.Add(new ListItem() { Text = answer.answerText, Value = answer.score.ToString() });
                }
            }
        }
```

However, this always shows me the first block. How can I implement "paging" here? I tried using `Session`, but this is not available in a usercontrol.

This is my panel:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="TestPanel" DefaultButton="ProceedLanguageButton">

    <div>
        <h1><asp:Label runat="server" ID="bodyTitle"></asp:Label></h1>
    </div>

    <div>
        <asp:Label runat="server" id="bodyText"></asp:Label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="questionLabel"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <cc1:languageradiobuttonlist id="QuestionsLanguageRadioButtonList" runat="server" repeatdirection="Vertical" basekey="Questions" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <asp:Label runat="server" id="concludingText"></asp:Label>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>


<div class="contentSeperator"></div>

<%--BUTTONS--%>
<div>
    <cc1:LanguageButton runat="server" ID="ReturnLanguageButton" CssClass="defaultButton Actie"
        CausesValidation="false" OnClick="ReturnLanguageButton_Click" Key="Test:Return" />
    <cc1:LanguageButton runat="server" ID="ProceedLanguageButton" CssClass="defaultButton Proceed"
        CausesValidation="false" OnClick="ProceedLanguageButton_Click" Key="Test:Proceed" />
</div>
```

Note: this is not a MVC project.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using a Data Bound .Net control that already has paging built in?  Seems like you might be trying to re-invent the wheel here.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a ListView or a Repeater...

Comment: Good point. I guess I'm overcomplicating things.